# Paring Json Array in php

Tags: php, android, parsing, arrays

Hello everyone i am facing a problem.
i am receiving an array from android.i want to parse the array and then store it into the mysql database but the code is not working. my code is as follows.Thanks in advance.

```
String timeArray;
JSONArray jss=new JSONArray();
        for(int i=0;i<time.size();i++){
            jss.put(time.get(i));
        }
    timeArray=jss.toString();
```

and my Server side Code is

```
$myArray=$_POST['items'];// here i receive ["3:02","9:12","12:20"]

$myArray1=json_decode($myArray);

   foreach($myArray1 as $row){

        $sql="INSERT INTO `time`(`time`) VALUES('$row')";
        mysql_query($sql) or die("Problem occured while inserting");

   }
```

Comment: As far as I think you are not getting the right data set, like the format of the json object is not correct. Add the response to jsonlint and check whether your formatting is correct or not.

Comment: format is correct i checked it. i think problem is with decoding

Comment: Can you paste the response that you are having in $myArray

Comment: its working when i pass a hardcoded value i.e.'["3:02","9:12","12:20"]' i don't know how to get response if i am sending data from android to php.

Comment: just try to print the array in eclipse console on your android app that you are trying to send over to the webservice.

Comment: @arsalanqamar so why do you say `// here i receive ["3:02","9:12","12:20"]` if you don't receive it ?

Comment: i insert the whole value in my sql table thats why i am saying this. value inserted successfully

Answer (score 0):

If you want `json_encode` to return an array you need to call the function with the optional `assoc` parameter set to `true`:

```
$myArray1=json_decode($myArray, true);
```

Otherwise json_decode will return an object instead of an array. See the [PHP manual for `json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more info.

EDIT: You'll need to post more detail about what is not working, including error messages, to get help. There are too many variables you in your code for me to pinpoint the issue. Running the following code:

```
$myArray1=json_decode('["3:02","9:12","12:20"]', true);
foreach($myArray1 as $row){
    echo "INSERT INTO `time`(`time`) VALUES('$row');\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
INSERT INTO `time`(`time`) VALUES('3:02');
INSERT INTO `time`(`time`) VALUES('9:12');
INSERT INTO `time`(`time`) VALUES('12:20');
```

So your issue is likely not actually caused by parsing JSON data into a PHP array. The first thing I would check is whether or not you've actually created a successful connection to your database before attempting insert queries.

Comment: there is no problem in connection i inserted other values .its working fine. i think problem is with json_decode.

Comment: what is the output of your script if you add `var_dump($myArray1)`?

Comment: its working fine if i pass a value '["3:02","9:12","12:20"]'. my log is also showing the same value.

Comment: So if it's working fine when you pass the value you expect to be in `$_POST['items']`, but not when you try to `json_decode($_POST['items'])`, what do you get when you `var_dump($_POST['items'])`?

Comment: i have found out a solution i will be pleased to share it with you .Instead of sending json array i am sending string with comma separated value i.e 3:02,9:12,12:20 and then insert it using the explode() function is this the right way?

Comment: It will work assuming your input is perfectly valid, but splitting on commas isn't ideal. If you get input with commas in the values for some reason it could mess up your parsing. If you have the server side code working with receiving a comma separated string then I would guess the error is coming from input that isn't valid JSON, or isn't a JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

All you to do is the following :

```
$myArray=json_decode($_POST['items']);
foreach($myArray as $time){
    $sql="INSERT INTO `time`(`time`) VALUES('$time')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die("Problem occured while inserting");
}
```

Avoid SQL injection, by escaping post values , or upgrading to mysqli prepared statements.

EDIT:

`@arsalanqamar` [you said it works when hardcoded in your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4178829/arsalan-qamar) this means you are not receiving the JSON

You POST pair value should look like this:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("items", timeArray));
```

Comment: instead of saying answer dont work which is very "helpful" you should make an effort to provide details. at the end of the day it is to help you.

Comment: i am trying to parse a json array in php in this format i.e. ["3:02","9:12","12:20"]. i am trying to parse it and then store these values in the database . i tried your code but it didn't parse.

Comment: @arsalanqamar but [you said it works when hardcoded in your comments](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4178829/arsalan-qamar) this means you are not receiving the JSON

Comment: i am doing the same thing as you suggest. but there is still a problem . i am successfully storing this whole string ( ["3:02","9:12","12:20"]) the database that means i am getting the array but i failed when i tried to parse it and store in the database.

Comment: @arsalanqamar why do you take so long to respond

Comment: i am sorry but i have internet connection problem thats why i respond late. i have find out a solution ..instead of sending a jsonarray i am sending comma separated values and then parse and store them in the database